# My dll is not working in a project on another pc

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I wrote my class library in c#.  It uses a couple of nuget packages and another dll downloaded from the Internet (visacomlib.dll) I connect it to another (console) project, this bundle works on my computer.

If you compile the final project, it also works.  However, if you transfer the compiled project to another PC, an error appears:

`System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLID`.

Comment: COM components have to be registered ... whatever `visacomlib.dll` is it should be registered (but prolly it cannot as it needs whole program - you should install program which this library is a part on another PC)

Comment: @Selvin, i tried to do it with regasm.  But she swears that my library does not have a strong name, I still do not understand how to fix it.

Comment: regasm is for managed assemblies which needs to be visible as COM ... you need rather use `regsvr32` as long it this library can be selfregistered ... but I doubt ... I'm pretty sure that you need to install whole program

Comment: @Selvin, You are probably right.  I will try to find with what software it could install, I hope this helps.  Thank you!

Comment: @Selvin, the installation helped in part. A similar error continues to be issued, although its text has changed slightly: `2022-11-11 10:38:57.7257 [INFO]: HELLO!
HRESULT = 80040015
Unhandled exception. System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040015): HRESULT = 80040015
   at VisaComLib`

Comment: Magic. If the same project is published through Visual Studio, and not through Rider, then everything works. I still can't figure out what they do differently.

Answer (score 0):

I partially solved the problem in the following way:

1. Be sure to install the NI_visa drivers.
2. Assembly in Rider did not work. On another PC I get the following error:

```cs
Unhandled exception. System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040015) HRESULT = 80040015
at VisaComLib.ResourceManagerClass.Open(String ResourceName, AccessMode mode, Int32 openTimeout, String OptionString)
```

3. However, I built the same project with default settings in Visual Studio and everything worked.

If everything turns out so well to make a working assembly in Rider, I will supplement this answer.